# Multilingual and SEO URLs - best practice?

Tags: htaccess, seo, multilingual

What would you recommend as a URL structure for setting up a multilingual site when optimizing for SEO?

I'm thinking:

```
www.yoursite.com/en/some-category/some-article/
www.yoursite.com/sv/en-kategori/en-artikel/ (Swedish)
```

Or would you prefer creating a subdomain (i.e. `sv.yoursite.com`) or similar instead?

From what I know it seems easier integrating a `/language/` directory when in combination with .htaccess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Working with multi-regional websites by Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html). It covers this in detail.